# HTML javascript dynamic table resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, html-table

I am trying to replicate this example 
http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html

When there is a large table it'll resize to 10 entries and page them accordingly. I don't need anything else ie. Don't need the Search bar

Currently I got the JS script from the website but I'm having trouble implementing this. Could someone please help me out. I have a table like so `<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">` with a thead and tfoot with this JavaScript code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );

    </script>
```

Right now it is not resizing the table. This might be a really basic implementation but I can't seem to get it working. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle showing what you actually have?

Comment: I do not have it on a server .. it's local HTML coding and i can't post it here since it's a lot of coding (a lot of rows in the table) ... Take the example on the website i provided .. i took that source code put it on my own HTML file and it doesn't seem to do the table resize `<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Position</th>
       <th>Office</th>
       <th>Age</th>
       <th>Start date</th>
       <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tfoot>`

Comment: It's hard to give you any advice if we acn't see your code. Could be a problem of css, or scripts inclusions, or script version and so on...
I just copy-pasted the code to jsfiddle and it works https://jsfiddle.net/mwwp9b7m/

Comment: @Yuri I'm probably putting the JS Script in the wrong place ... should they go at the bottom of the table </table> as  `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">` and close it with `</script>` or should they go in a separate file and reference it?

Comment: I usually put <script> at the bottom page as it speed up content loading, but if you use `$(document).ready(....)`, your js code will be executed only when the page is fully loaded, whether you put it in `<head>` or `<body>`

Comment: I copied and pasted the exact code from fiddle. With the `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">` at the bottom of the table .. The 'SEARCH Name' SEARCH Position etc comes up but Not the previous and next page and page numbers .. i also made reference to css `
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.dataTables.min.css">
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
` Still no luck

Comment: And the datatables.css file?

Comment: AHHH ha! Thanks so much Yuri i was just missing couple of the css file and js .. Thanks a lot bud!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CSS in your HTML

```
tfoot input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Its solve your problem?

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/20/

Comment: Sorry ignorant question you know the javascript .. do i put it on the bottom of the table or should i create a new .js file and link it using  `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dataTable.js"></script>` in the head node. Sorry not an expert on html coding

Comment: @civic.sir no problem